# unable to load model in Flask using scikit-learn

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn

Created a random forest model and tried to deploy it as API using `Flask` `python3.7` on `ubuntu 18`.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import svm
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response, redirect, Response
import pickle
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

model = 'model.joblib'

@app.route("/score", methods=['GET'])
def linkscoring():
    '''
    some Logic
    '''

    analysis_dataset = analysis_dataset.fillna(0)
    link_score = analysis_dataset.sum(axis=1)

    link_score   = loaded_model.predict_proba(analysis_dataset)
    prob_info_present = round(100*(link_score[0][1]),2)
    return jsonify({"message":prob_info_present})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loaded_model = joblib.load(model)
    app.run()
```

But on local system I'm getting this error `NameError: name 'loaded_model' is not defined`

I also tried to load model within the function. but didn't work out. Only goal is load model. i don't know what i'm doing wrong.
Any help will be apericated.

Comment: How do you run your flask instance?

Comment: @yeg on local with vs code and on production server with mod_wsgi

Comment: Unless you run this module as main program of python's interpreter (like pyton thismodulename.py) loaded_model = joblib.load(model) will not get executed and loaded_model var will not register as global.

Comment: @yeg okay, I understand that. Is there any other solution?

Comment: One will be replacing model = 'model.joblib' with loaded_model = joblib.load('model.joblib')

Comment: @yeg Did that. didn't work its keep on loading the model and other API also not responding.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your model variable is not set to global.
Try this here:

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.externals import joblib
from sklearn import svm
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response, redirect, Response
import pickle
import json


app = Flask(__name__)

def init():
    global model
    model = joblib.load("model.h5")

@app.route("/score", methods=['GET'])
def linkscoring():
    '''
    some Logic
    '''

    analysis_dataset = analysis_dataset.fillna(0)
    link_score = analysis_dataset.sum(axis=1)

    link_score   = loaded_model.predict_proba(analysis_dataset)
    prob_info_present = round(100*(link_score[0][1]),2)
    return jsonify({"message":prob_info_present})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    init()
    app.run()
```